# Will custom parts be included in .IO-files?

Tags: bricklink-studio

In a Stud.IO project I made I'm missing a specific printed part that isn't available in Stud.IO. So I **used the Part Designer to create a custom part**, which is basically just a normal 1x1 tile with the print as a decal. I got this properly imported into Stud.IO and by giving the part the correct BrickLink number in the Part Designer, I also got it to automatically link to the proper LEGO piece and the instructions show the proper part number, too.

This is all well and good, but now I want to share the **Stud.IO file, with someone who doesn't necessarily have that part**. Now the question is, **will the custom part automatically be included in the Stud.IO model** and work as expected or would the other person need to import that part on their system, too? If it doesn't work right away, what would happen instead? Would the part just be missing, as if the pieces are just not in the model or would anything else happen (like an error or some kind of dummy part being shown)?

Comment: Seems easiest to me to just test on another system or reach out to someone to test the .io file for you...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve That's what I since did and in fact it does all work properly. ;-) Still, a proper SE question seemed like a good idea anyway (although, I don't quite feel like giving a one-line-answer based on hearsay now either.)

Comment: It is completely reasonable to self-answer questions on StackExchange.  And it won't be just one sentence if you explain how you tested it.  I'd make a heading with the word "Yes" by `# Yes` at the top so the simple answer is easily evident.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I did the obvious thing and just tried it. That is to say, I gave the Stud.IO file to someone who opened it on their own system where the part hadn't been imported from the Part Designer. And in fact **yes, it works**, meaning he could see the part with the print decal in the model and the instructions and it even linked to the correct BrickLink piece.